# Remove favorites action menu and screen options panel

Tags: wp-admin

I was playing with: `$wp_meta_boxes`, `$menu` and `$submenu` global arrays to remove "things" on admin dashboard (using unset on PHP `foreach` iterations).

Now I'm stuck trying to remove without using jQuery or JavaScript:

1. Favorites action menu.
2. Screen options panel.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once did extend the screen panels, putting a third one next to screen and help. But that was mainly by javascript. So you can remove them with javscript I'm sure. There were no hooks or so, that's why I opened a ticket as well with a patch because I thought that it would be useful to have. I got some traction lately, so maybe this feature will be implemented in 3.1 / 3.2:

- [Ticket #9657 - Allow custom screen_meta dropdown panels](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/9657)

Maybe the patch still works so you can apply the patch and use the hooks.

Some kind of related / master ticket is:

- [Ticket #11517 - Make Admin more MVC-like](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11517)

Answer (score 0):

## How to remove the favorite actions menu

Hook a filter onto `favorite_actions` and return an empty array.

```
function remove_favorite_actions() {
    return array();
}
add_filter( 'favorite_actions', 'remove_favorite_actions' );
```